# Do any hypervisors support vTPM?

Tags: virtualization, tpm

I am trying to use vtpm to provide remote attestation for VMs, but I do not know what hypervisors support vtpm. Does anyone know?

Comment: This is more of a product question than a security question.

Answer (score 1):

Xen asserts they have support for it: wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Virtual_Trusted_Platform_Module_(vTPM)

I can't find much that verifies that any of the VMware platforms have it. This is really all I could find: https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp#com.vmware.vsphere.security.doc_50/GUID-E9B71B85-FBA3-447C-8A60-DEE2AE1A405A.html?resultof=%2522%2554%2550%254d%2522%2520%2522%2574%2570%256d%2522%2520

Looks like its in Windows Server 2016's Hyper-V: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0e64d1ec-1a56-4c7b-a55c-fa8f2aa3807b/hyper-2016-technical-preview-2-could-not-start-shielded-vms-after-enabling-vtpm?forum=winserverhyperv

Virtualbox has a addon for it. www.trust.rub.de/projects/vTPM/